# Angular 2: recover from http request, and redo the request

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have some basic flow I would like to implement using angular 2 and rxjs
this is the flow:

Asumming the user is loged in, for each request:

1. If request fail, catch the error,
2. do something async (relogin in the background)
3. if success re send the failed request
4. if fails throw the error.

   ```
   class MyHttpWrapper {
    ctor(private http:Http) {}

    get (url, options) {
        //Do some pre request things with the options and url

        return this.get(url,options)
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .catch((err, source) => {
                             // Here i want to reloging
                             someService.login().subscribe(res => 
                              //Here i want to re-execute the original request and return it to the caller of the myHttpwrapper.get() caller
                             ).catch(err => 
                                 //return error to the caller of the myHttpWrapper.get() 
                             )                               
                        }
    }
   ```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try something like that:

```
return this.http.get(url,options)
           .catch((err, source) => {
             return someService.login()
                       .flatMap((res) => {
                         return this.http.get(url,options);
                       });
           })
           .map(res => res.json());
```

If there is an error on both `login` and the second `get`, the error will be thrown to the second callback of the `subscribe` method.

Comment: Will a `.catch` after the `flatMap` will catch the error on login or the second get?

Comment: Yes it'll catch such error since it will apply on the observable returned by `flatMap`.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question that is a bit off from this one. What if i want this error will be handle by  another class but I dont want `myHttpWrapper` to know, i would like to do something like that: create a object `errors = new Subject()` and in the catch I want to `error.next(url,options)` is that possible?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the right approach. The `errors` must be part of a shared service so other parts of your application can subscribe on it.

Comment: Hi again, so I am try to do that.. and im stuck., I have added to `MyHttp` `public errors = new Subject()` and in my `.catch` im doing `return errors.next(err, source, url , options)` and I have a listener to that is being invoked on error the problem is that non of the others parameters (except the first one) are being transferred.(all are undefined) and I cant seems to return new observable that listener

Comment: In fact the `next` method accepts only one parameter. So you could try to pass parameters this way: `return errors.next({err, source, url , options});`. You can get them in your listener using `source`, `url`, ... properties.

Comment: The subscribe on the errors is returning undefined, What im doing wrong?